# public static IEnumerable<int> Method

Tags: c#, syntax, ienumerable

I am trying to call the function but I cannot. Is there any specific way to call IEnumerable methods?

This is the function.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> UpTo(this int minValue, int maxValue)
{
    return  maxValue < minValue ? Enumerable.Empty<int>() : Enumerable.Range(minValue, maxValue - minValue + 1);
}
```

And I am trying to call the function like this

```
var newContainer = new List<int>();
newContainer.Add(1);
newContainer.Add(2);
newContainer.Add(3);
newContainer.Add(4);

var formattedContainer = newContainer.UpTo(10);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Modify an existing enumeration or just create a new one?

Comment: Just create a new one, an call the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a simple parameter mismatch: Your extension method declares an `int` as `this`-parameter, whereas you try to apply it to a `List<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

The function should be:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> UpTo(this Enumerable<int>, int minValue, int maxValue)
{
    return  maxValue < minValue ? Enumerable.Empty<int>() : Enumerable.Range(minValue, maxValue - minValue + 1);
}
```

Comment: I'm missing the parameter name.

Comment: for completness: It should be placed in a static class

Comment: And even if it had a name, it's not used, so it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new enumeration, like Enumerable.Range, then do not use a this parameter and do not call it on a list, make it work just like Enumerable.Range. `MyClassName.UpTo(2, 3)` makes sense, but I fail to see what you mean by `newContainer.UpTo(10);`. This latter call is equivalent to `MyClassname.UpTo(newContainer, 10)`, and the first parameter is not a number.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't work because you extend `int` but you are using it on `List<int>`. If you want to extend `int` with a method `UpTo` that creates a sequence from this number to an upper bound `maxValue`:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> UpTo(this int minValue, int maxValue)
{
    if (maxValue > minValue)
        return Enumerable.Range(minValue, maxValue - minValue + 1);
    else
        return Enumerable.Empty<int>();
}
```

Now you need to call it on an `int`:

```
IEnumerable<int> sequence = 4.UpTo(10);
Console.Write(string.Join(",", sequence));
```

which outputs: `4,5,6,7,8,9,10`

---

If you want to extend `List<T>` you need it as first parameter with the `this` keyword.

```
public static void AddUpTo(this List<int> list, int minValue, int maxValue)
{
    if (maxValue > minValue)
    {
        list.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(minValue, maxValue - minValue));
    }
}
```

or, if you want to allow an `IEnumerable<int>` which is less efficient:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> UpTo(this IEnumerable<int> sequence, int minValue, int maxValue)
{
    if (maxValue > minValue)
        return sequence.Concat(Enumerable.Range(minValue, maxValue - minValue));
    else
        return sequence;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to modify the function, I just don't know why I can not call it.

Comment: @Rubenex: I've edited it accordingly.